# Do I have my Ubuntu partition in many locations?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am new to the world of Linux, computers, and computer science, and I installed Ubuntu a few months ago. I confess I am not really proficient on the technical side of computers as of right now, so I really do not understand much of the technical words.

I installed Ubuntu along side my Windows 10 by allocating around 100GB (I think, seems too large) or so from my DATA drive which was mostly free. Since I cannot completely recall how much I allocated, I want to increase the size of my partition with GParted. When I look online, the screenshots that are posted look different from mine when it comes to the partitions shown with GParted.

*Image showing the Details*

[image]

*Screenshot that shows the `df -k` and `df -h` commands, as well as the Gparted information*

[image]

I plan to make Linux my main OS from now on, but I may need Windows from time to time so I need it to be around for those times.

Does my partition seem close to running out? If I am correct and the Ubuntu partition is in different places, what are the consequences of this?

Comment: Hye! Welcome to Askubuntu. Instead of adding screenshots, you should consider copy and paste the text here. Images take more space(and in your case it's hard to read too). For example, to show your partitioning, you can paste the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: You have linux partition at `/dev/sda8` and `/dev/sda9`.  Former for linux os and data and latter for enabling suspend/hibernation. Everything else is windows clutter.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. I added screenshots to show all the information that could help in getting an answer.  Just in case I was not communicating clearly. Do you happen to know if the way the Ubuntu partition is set up is correct or good? When others post questions regarding the Ubuntu partition they include screenshots that just show one partition such as /dev/sda3, for example. The screenshots are usually neat whereas mine is cluttered.

Comment: you have two linux partitions which is `/dev/sda8` and `/dev/sda9`.

Comment: @David your disk setup looks fine, and as I see it, no reason to change it. You have plenty of room on your Ubuntu partition sda8. However, I wouldn't mount your Windows C: drive in Ubuntu (without some Windows settings changed).

Comment: @kashish There's no way to copy/paste info from a gparted window, so images are fine in this case. A gparted image tells a lot more information than a `sudo fdisk -l`. And technically, `fdisk` isn't for GPT formatted disks.

Comment: @heynnema So if I ever need to increase the space for Ubuntu, if that day ever arises, I can just increase /dev/ssa8?

Comment: @David there's no room to resize /dev/sda8 without first shrinking /dev/sda6... and since it's NTFS, do that from Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The in a nutshell answer is that your hard drive has plenty of space available. Both for your Windows installation and your Ubuntu installation.

As you stated, if you want to make Ubuntu your primary OS see more info in this reply.

As mentioned below, 2 partitions are being used for Ubuntu, the rest are partitions for your Windows. These include partitions for booting, efi, windows recovery and your restoration partition.

I disagree with some of the other user comments.
Having one primary Operating System on the hard drive, whether it be Windows or Linux and then using VMware or Virtual Box is a very valid and useful way to have your system setup.

Doing the setup this way: you have Windows installed on hard drive and Virtual Box and then a Linux installation you can be booted into Windows and launch the VM from inside Windows. No booting into a dual boot environment.

You can also do Linux on the hard drive and use Virtual Box and install Windows as the VM.

Using VM's means:
You will not get problematic grub or boot errors.
You can install many VM;Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora, etc...
You can have master backup copies of the VM's so if one get corrupt easily use your master copy and get set back up within a few minutes
Have snapshots of your system
and many more benefits

All partitions but 2 appear to be Windows based.
You appear to have plenty of room on all partitions from what I see.
SDA 1-7 are Windows, SDA 8 & 9 are linux. You have your Ubuntu on the ext4 and then a SWAP partition.

SDA 7 has your actual restore / Recovery partition.

Do you have recovery disks made?

> Having your recovery disc created ensures if you decide to wipe
>   everything out and get back to a fresh OEM Factory defaults install
>   you can. Imperative Suggestion to make sure you have them created.

You could wipe your whole hard drive, install Ubuntu, Install Virtual Box, then use the Windows Discs and create a Virtual Machine in Virtual Box.
Best of both worlds and performance on a VM is really good usually even on 700MB to 1.5 GB of memory.

Comment: As in wipe out the drive, make Ubuntu my main OS, and install Virtual Box for Windows 10? I have been thinking of doing something similar to see if that helps out the graying of my screens when I run something that seems resource-hungry.

Comment: VM's have good performance. I've used them both ways - Windows as host, Linux as guest and vice versa. And you never have to re-boot to get into the other OS. Networking, wireless, sound, etc... should all work. I never dual boot anymore. Only use VM for a second OS.

Comment: @David Windows VM's cannot be used for doing things like BIOS updates. Keep your Windows installation as is.

Comment: @burliway777 wipe the drive and create a VM? No way. Not good advice.

Comment: @David *(...) to see if that helps out the graying of my screens when I run something that seems resource-hungry* No, it will NOT.

Answer (score -1):

The ext4 file type is your linux partition which is /dev/sda8 
If you want to extend the partition you need to format any of the ntfs partition to ext4 Make sure you wont format the partition were windows 10 is installed. windows 10 is either installed in /dev/sda4 or /dev/sda6

Comment: Blatantly wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask me, you don't seem to have the cleanest partition scheme ever.

But hey, **it does work**! It's not technically bad or anything. You need a root partition wich you have; you need a swap and you have that too; and then you need a /home directory wich is used to storage your files such as documents, images, music and stuff (and yes, even if you have a whole disk or other partition meant for this task you still need a /home directory for what I know.

Besides some basic structure it's really a matter of preference how to use your disks and partitions. [I use this simple scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sa3L.jpg) and it works for me.

If you claim to be *new to the world of computers* I think you did a great job setting all that config by yourself, using Gparted and getting the dual boot done. So congrats and welcome to the amazing community of linux.

Comment: Their partitioning looks fine. What do you see that's wrong with it? And "merge" sda4/5/6? What about their Windows installation? Not good advice.

Comment: You are totally right @heynnema I didn't see that the label OS was actually Windows. To merge those partitions would have been a big mistake. I've already edited my answer, thank you for making me notice that.

Regarding what I see "wrong", as I mentioned it is not wrong at all. For me it's a little bit messy that's all. The labels and having so many partitions. Idk, is sd6 the /home dir? What's sd5 for? And as himself mentioned, the root has a lot more space than it really needs.

That's from my perspective.

Comment: sda8 is / and /home. sda5 looks like another diagnostic/restore partition... it does look a little strange... but you don't touch diag/restore partitions.